# Why did Latin language stop being in use in the 18th century?

Tags: 18th-century, latin-language

Why did Latin language fall?

According to Wikipedia, in the 18th century the Latin language stopped to be the language in academia and politics. It is written there in the wiki article that Latin was replaced by regional languages (French, German etc.).

My questions:

1. Why did it happen?
2. Why in the 18th century?

Thank you.

Comment: Given it far outlived the Romans, the question to consider is why not earlier?

Comment: Have you read the whole WP page on Latin, especially the History section? Latin hadn't been used as a spoken language for centuries (except for a brief resurgence during the Renaissance). Personally, I'd say French was very much on the upswing (Louis XIV, Revolution, Napoleon), as was Nationalism and the idea creeping in over time that education should be accessible to everybody. Latin ceased to offer significant advantages as *lingua franca*, and started to become an obstacle.

Comment: Probably a knock-on effect of the Reformation; one of the goals of the Reformation throughout Europe was to promote the vernacular over Latin.

Comment: Good question. I doubt it is only a protestant issue because: a) some reformers wrote in Latin b) catholic europe also changed. As to why not earlier, vernacular would not be worthy before the national languages were unified in orthography and grammar, as a text in a regional dialect would be safely understood only in a small region.